# npm start not working for react while install react script (react script : 3.4.0 version)

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to React js, While using npm start after install the react not working,I tried every process but no use. Thanks in advance

> **Error**

cricdost@0.1.0 start C:\xampp\htdocs\cd-web
react-scripts start

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
>   It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"webpack": "4.41.2"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.39.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cricdost@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cricdost@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XSC-10261\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-20T04_56_31_650Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same error. The solution that I found is to do the step-6 as described in Error message. That is to delete **"webpack" folder** of **node_module folder** under your root projects directory. For example

Assume that you installed **"npm install create-react-app"** in **D:\Projects** folder.
And then you ran **"npx create-react-app firstproject"** in **D:\Projects** folder. So, your actual react project folder is **"D:\Projects\firstproject"**.

So, what I want to tell is **don't** delete **"webpack" folder** in **"D:\Projects\firstproject\node_module"** directory. Instead, **delete** **"webpack" folder** in **"D:\Projects\node_module"** directory.

And then, you can run **"npm start"** command in your actual react project directory **"D:\Projects\firstproject"**.

I hope, this will work for you.

Comment: i faced the same problem from two days. but i am unable to delete webpack folder. their is not any option to delete this folder. my dir is " Document/my-app/node-modules   "

Comment: another option is to install completely new react project with "npm install create-react-app" command in new directory. And then create new react app with "npx  create-react-app [AppName]" in that new directory.